# Problem with get_page_by_path() using with WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, theme-development

I get error when i use get_page_by_path() with WP_Query in a php class. I use ***after_switch_theme*** and ***switch_theme*** in that class. And while the theme is activated then everything is fine as expected. But the problem is, while i switching theme then browser show me an error.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\wordpress-theme-test\wp-includes\post.php on line 4470

I try to figure out the error
`

```
public function theme_deactivation() {
    $pages = array( 'member-login', 'member-account', 'member-register', 'member-password-lost', 'member-password-reset' );

    foreach ( $pages as $slug ) {
        $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=' . $slug );

        $page = get_page_by_path( $query );
        wp_delete_post( $page->ID, true );
    }
}
```

And I think, the main problem is get_page_by_path(). It's first and required parameter is  *$page_path (string)*  and WP_Query is an object. And error say ***WP_Query could not be converted to string*** (for get_page_by_path())

Is there any way to solve the problem??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to try and pass a query result to `get_page_by_path()`. The point of `WP_Query` is to query for a selection of posts based on given criteria, while `get_page_by_path()` is for retrieving a single specific post based on its path. There's no reason you'd need to use them together.

If you want to delete posts based on their slug, then you don't need a query at all:

```
$pages = array( 'member-login', 'member-account', 'member-register', 'member-password-lost', 'member-password-reset' );

foreach ( $pages as $slug ) {
    $page = get_page_by_path( $slug );

    if ( $page ) {
        wp_delete_post( $page->ID, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me explain why i need to query posts. I need to query posts before delete, if those posts are exist then delete those posts.

Comment: You don't need to query to do that, just check if `get_page_by_path()` returns a result. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob.